# JSP doesn't recognize stylesheet

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a home page jsp that is styled just right. At the bottom I have a button that takes you to another JSP. This JSP doesn't seem to respond to any CSS styling. I have pretty much the same layout on each page and I want basically the same styling, the second page just does not work the same way the first one does; what gives ? I also tried affixing the same stylesheet to both pages but the problem was the same, the first page was styled the second was not. Does it have something to do with the second page being linked to ?

Thanks!

EDIT: you should know the files are in the correct folders, all css files are in the css folder as stated and the two pages are at the base dir of the web app.

page 1:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Flash Card Shark!</title>
        <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/HomeScreenCustomSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />        
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Brave the Treacherous Waters</h1>
        <div class="centerLoginScreen">

            <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Home" method="POST">
                <p>username: <input type="text" name="username" class="username"/></p>
                <p>password: <input type="pass" name="password" class="username" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="submit" id="loginbutton" class="buttons" /></p>
            </form>
            <div class="buttons">
                <p><a href="registrationPage.jsp"><button id="registerbutton">Register a new account</button></a>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <script src="js/homescreen.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

style sheet for page 1, this one works:

```
.centerLoginScreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Yep! */
    width: 48%;
    height: 59%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}

.buttons {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: max-content;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

page 2:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome To Flash Card Shark</title>
        <link href="css/registrationPageCustomSheet.css" rel="stylsheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="centerRegistrationScreen">
            <form action="registrationPage.jsp" method="POST">

                <p>username: <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
                <p>password: <input type="text" name="password"/></p>
                <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
                <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /></p>
                <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>

                <sql:setDataSource dataSource="jdbc/FlashCardShark" url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/FlashCards"
                                       driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" user="maxbisesi"
                                       password="Basketball12"
                                       var="registerDB" />

                <sql:update dataSource="${registerDB}">
                    Insert into FlashUser(username,password,firstname,lastname,email) values(?,?,?,?,?)
                    <sql:param value="${param.username}"/>
                    <sql:param value="${param.password}"/>
                    <sql:param value="${param.firstname}"/>
                    <sql:param value="${param.lastname}"/>
                    <sql:param value="${param.email}" />
                </sql:update>

            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
```

style sheet for page 2, changes to this sheet don't do anything:

```
.centerRegistrationScreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Yep! */
    width: 48%;
    height: 59%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/HomeScreenCustomSheet.css" />
```

or

```
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/HomeScreenCustomSheet.css"%></style>
```

Comment: Nice! the scriptlet worked. However I've read that your not really supposed to use scriptlets anymore ? Surely you can include files with jstl right ?

Comment: glad it worked. I'm not really sure as I didn't work with jstl in a long time

Comment: Do you have any idea why this was the way it was ?

Comment: Also use <c:import> instead of the scriptlet and it worked fine